# Dell Wireless 360 bluetooth not working in lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, dell, bluetooth

Guys i just recently installed lubuntu 14.04 lts on my old dell latitude D530 with a Dell wireless 360 bluetooth module in it. Love the OS very much but the bluetooth is not working. Bluetooth is enabled by hardware switch but still hcitool scan doesn't detect the device.

This is the Output of hcitool when i command it to scan.

```
   mtzlab@mtzlab-Latitude-D530:~$ hcitool scan
   Device is not available: No such device
```

Please help me i have been trying to fix this problem but didn't got any success.

Comment: what's the output of `rfkill list all`

Comment: Show the results of `usb-devices`  You may want to copy the info from terminal and paste at paste.ubuntu.com then just post the url

Comment: the output of rfkill is only displaying wlan device phy0 which is nor soft blocked neither hard blocked and there is no bluetooth device. @Ron

Comment: The output of usb-devices is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/10972560 @Jeremy31

Comment: Is the device enabled in BIOS as I see nothing resembling bluetooth from your paste.  You should also check to see if the card is seated well in the socket

Comment: it is enabled in the BIOS and the card is also seated well in the socket which i confirmed just now. @Jeremy31

Comment: Post `lspci -nn; lsusb`  I think they normally show up with a vendor ID of 0a5c  And can you try a Live version of 15.04 and see if anything different shows up in `lsusb`

Comment: here's the output for the command http://paste.ubuntu.com/10975483/ . and i have tried it on another flavour of ubuntu (mate edition) 14.04 and it didn't work either. Could it be something wrong with the kernel version @Jeremy31

Comment: It is likely a kernel bug that prevents it from discovering the device as your card should show in `lsusb` as `413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth`  You can report a bug by starting [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rfkill ublock all` in your terminal.

Comment: Didn't worked. The output of "rkill list all" only shows wlan which  is neither soft nor hard blocked.